# CakePHP 3.x: Applying application rules to multiple entities

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

#### The problem

I've a problem relating to how best to implement business rules on a table which should apply to the entities being created with knowledge of one another. From my research thus far, I suspect this goes against the inner-workings of CakePHP and there may well be another feature of the framework I have missed that allows this.

The entities in question have a `hasMany` association, through which data is being saved. For example, `UsersTable` and `Questionnaires` are associated through `UsersQuestionnairesTable`. As such, I note the `buildRules` method of `UsersQuestionnairesTable` is run `n` times, where `n` is the number of associated entities being created.

#### The Goal

My goal is to apply a build rule which ensures that one (and only one) of the `UsersQuestionnaire` rows in the request data is marked as the `default: true` should no other `UsersQuestionnairesTable` records exist for the user.

The present result is actually that by applying this in `UsersQuestionnairesTable::buildRules`, upon attempting to create a `User` with some `Questionnaires` associated with it through `UsersQuestionnairesTable`, it will only pass validation if the first data row of the payload that it marshals into an entity has the `default: true`. Therefore, it does not work for multiple entity creation as it will fail for the second row as `default: false`, thus not creating the `User`.

#### What I understand/have tried

As I understand it, the `buildRules` method of a `Table` class is a useful place to enfore application logic rules that apply to entities. For example, that an email is unique in the database.

From [CakePHP 3.x Cookbook > Validating Data > Applying Application Rules](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/validation.html#applying-application-rules)

> Where validation ensures the form or syntax of your data is correct, rules focus on comparing data against the existing state of your application and/or network.
>
> These types of rules are often referred to as ‘domain rules’ or ‘application rules’. CakePHP exposes this concept through ‘RulesCheckers’ which are applied before entities are persisted. Some example domain rules are:
>
> - Ensuring email uniqueness
> - State transitions or workflow steps (e.g., updating an invoice’s status).
> - Preventing the modification of soft deleted items.
> - Enforcing usage/rate limit caps.

I'd like to apply a similar rule to the entity during creation but with knowledge of other entities in the request data such that I can access all the `UsersQuestionnairesTable` entities being created to inspect their `deafult` value, and if none is found to be `true`, have the function fail and all entities not be created.

At present, this conditional rule applied to each entity during the creation process but before saving (though incorrect) should illustrate the desired end goal.

**UsersQuestionnairesTable**:

```
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $enforceFirstAsDefault = function ($entity) {
        $count = $this->find('all')
            ->where(['UserQuestionnaires.user_id' => $entity->user_id])
            ->andWhere(['Questionnaires.type_id' => 1])
            ->contain(['Questionnaires'])->count();

        if ($count == 0 && !$this->containsDefault($entity)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    };

    $rules->add($enforceFirstAsDefault, [
        'errorField' => 'no_default_identified',
        'message' => 'A default questionnaire is required')
    ]);
}

...

private function containsDefault($entities): bool 
{
    foreach ($entities as $entity) {
        if ($entity->is_default) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Because of the desire to fail before creation, `buildRules` on a model felt the most appropriate place to locate this logic to only apply to this model as:

- Behaviours are more suited to common behaviours between models
- Though you can access the data in `beforeMarshal` with `$event->getData()`, I understand this method is more suited to
  data manipulation prior to persistence and so is likely unsuitable
  for my needs.
- Having this functionality in many controllers which might be responsibile for creating `UsersQuestionnaires` records whether directly or via associations feels less DRY
  and SRP as it requires the `Users::create` (for example) to know of and act based
  upon whether a row in the `UsersQuestionnaires` payload data contains `default: true`, regardless of whether it's wrapped by a reusable helper of somekind.

#### The question

Is there something I'm missing about applying `buildRules` which will enable inspection of all entities that will or have been marshalled as a part of this request, such that the validaiton will only fail or pass once it has created all entities?

Perhaps a way to override/overload the `buildRules` with more request context? Or is this kind of business logic better suited in another location or using a different feature of the framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules functions can take a second parameter, which receives the options passed to the `save` function. So in your controller,

```
$this->UsersQuestionnaires->saveMany($entities, ['entities' => $entities]);
```

And then in your table:

```
$enforceFirstAsDefault = function ($entity, $options) {
    // Use $options['entities'] here to access the set of entities being saved
}
```

Comment: Worked great, thank you. Wasn't aware things filtered down from the ```save``` as far down as the rules. Could you link to the chapter of the cookbook/API docs that details this? Apologies if it's something I've missed on my travels, but thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing the connection mentioned explicitly in the sections on rules, validation or saving. Might be a good issue to raise on the documentation repository?